# Acessar dict dentro de lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como faço para acessar ao dicionário onde contenha o idioma português da lista abaixo?

Para acessar a chave: `variavel.foreign_names`, mas eu gostaria de pegar os valores que estâo dentro do dicionário com idioma português (o dicionário nem sempre será o último.)

```js
"foreignNames":[  
    {  
      "name":"Archange Avacyn",
      "language":"French",
      "multiverseid":411061
    },
    {  
      "name":"Erzengel Avacyn",
      "language":"German",
      "multiverseid":410731
    },
    {  
      "name":"Arcangelo Avacyn",
      "language":"Italian",
      "multiverseid":411391
    },
    {  
      "name":"大天使アヴァシン",
      "language":"Japanese",
      "multiverseid":411721
    },
    {  
      "name":"대천사 아바신",
      "language":"Korean",
      "multiverseid":412051
    },
    {  
      "name":"Arcanjo Avacyn",
      "language":"Portuguese (Brazil)",
      "multiverseid":412381
    }
```

Comment: Coloca o dicionário completo sff

Comment: @Miguel tem diferença colocar completo? o exemplo acima é uma situação real, apenas removi 4 ou 5 dicionarios para não ficar muito longo.

Comment: Ha ok, pronto pensei que podusse ser relevante. Dsculpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte:

```
dic = {"foreignNames":[  
    {  
      "name":"Archange Avacyn",
      "language":"French",
      "multiverseid":411061
    },
    {  
      "name":"Erzengel Avacyn",
      "language":"German",
      "multiverseid":410731
    },
    {  
      "name":"Arcangelo Avacyn",
      "language":"Italian",
      "multiverseid":411391
    },
    {  
      "name":"大天使アヴァシン",
      "language":"Japanese",
      "multiverseid":411721
    },
    {  
      "name":"대천사 아바신",
      "language":"Korean",
      "multiverseid":412051
    },
    {  
      "name":"Arcanjo Avacyn",
      "language":"Portuguese (Brazil)",
      "multiverseid":412381
    }
]}

def find_lang(lingua):
    for i in dic['foreignNames']:
        if(i['language'].lower().startswith(lingua.lower())):
            return i
    return None

lang = find_lang('portuguese')
print(lang) # {'name': 'Arcanjo Avacyn', 'language': 'Portuguese (Brazil)', 'multiverseid': 412381}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/MGouMz)

Ou, se preferires sem usar uma função:

```
...
lingua = 'Portuguese'

for i in dic['foreignNames']:
    if(i['language'].lower().startswith(lingua.lower())):
        print(dic_lingua) # {'name': 'Arcanjo Avacyn', 'language': 'Portuguese (Brazil)', 'multiverseid': 412381}
        break
else: # caso o for acima nao tenha sofrido break
    print('não encontrado')
```

Nota que estou a comparar `lower()` para tornar a buscar *case insensitive*, estou a presupor que virá de algum input externo, podes remover se vires que é mal empregue (ficando assim: `if(i['language'].startswith(lingua))`),  se quiseres fazer uma comparação precisa (mesmas palavras exatamente) fazes, `if(i['language'] == lingua)`

Uma maneira com list comprenssion, mas se me perguntares prefiro as soluções acima:

```
...
lingua = 'Portuguese'
dic_lingua = [x for x in dic['foreignNames'] if x['language'].startswith(lingua)]

if dic_lingua: # verificar se a lista resultante traz alguma entrada
    print(dic_lingua[0])
else:
    print('não encontrado')
```